# Assesing feasibility for OS X port

Tags: macos, bitmap

I need to figure out if porting an application to Mac OS X (not iOS) is feasible. I wrote some code for Mac around 20 years ago, but what I'm looking at now is completely different, and may require a complete re-write, which I cannot afford. After googling for some time, I found a variety of APIs, which appearing and get deprecated so often, that I feel completely lost.

1. The application draws through copying small fragments of bitmaps to the window. This is accomplished with BitBlt() on Windows or XCopyArea() on X11. In both cases, the source is stored in the video memory, so copying is really fast, 500K copies per second on a decent card, possibly more. On Mac, there used to be CopyBits() function which did the same, but it is now depreacted. I found CGContextDrawImage() which looks it's getting deprecated too, but copies from the user memory, and can only copy the whole image (not fragments). Is there any way to accomplish bitmap copying at decent speed?
2. I see everything is 64-bit. I would want to keep it in 32-bit for a number of reasons. 32-bit applications still seem to be supported, but with the fast pace deprecation, Apple may stop supporting at any time. Is this a correct assesment?
3. Software distribution. I cannot find any information on this. Looks like you need to be a member of the Apple Development program to be able to install your software on user's computers. Is this true? In some other places, I have read that any software must undergo Apple approval. Is this correct?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So much has changed in the past twenty years, that it may indeed be quite difficult to port your app directly to modern OS X. You may be better served by taking the general design concept and application objectives, and create a fresh implementation using up-to-date software technology.

1. Your drawing system might be much easier to do with modern APIs, but the first step is deciding which framework to use. Invest some time in reading the documentation and watching the many videos available on the Developer website. A logical place to start is [Getting Started with Graphics & Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_GraphicsImaging/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001000), but you may also wish to explore [Metal Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221) and [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=SpriteKit).
2. The notion of 64-bit vs 32-bit is irrelevant. All Mac computers run 64-bit code.
3. If you don't purchase a Developer program membership, you can still create an unsigned application with Xcode. It can be installed on another user's computer, but they'll need to specifically change the setting in System Preferences -> Security to "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere".

The [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) are very useful in understanding the concepts and benefits of advancements in these frameworks made over the past few years.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Doesn't look like any of the frameworks has an easy way to execute BitBlt() without too much overhead. Metal looks promising, although it's very recent and may not work with all devices they say.

Comment: 64/32-bit notion is relevant for me. My program is 32-bit, and looks like it is now supported on OS X. It would take me months to port to 64-bit and test. I'd rather leave it in 32-bit and spend my time elsewhere. I'm not using anywhere near 4GB of memory --- Does the signing process require Apple certification? Or do I just buy the certificate and sign it?

Comment: What language is your program written in?

Comment: When you register with the Apple Developer program, you receive a Developer ID certificate that you can use to sign self-distributed apps. If you wish to distribute your app through the App Store, there's a more involved approval process, but you don't need to do that if don't want to.

Comment: It's a mix - C/Pascal/Assembler. When it started, everything has just transitioned to 32-bit, so transition to 64-bit has not been anticipated (still don't understand the need for 64-bit). Mac was PPC back then, but now it's Intel - low hanging fruit :)

Comment: Well, that certainly brings back memories for me... many years ago when I was using Assembler to program for MS-OS/2. When IBM took over OS/2, it went from 16 to 32-bit and you had to "thunk" addresses — but, that's a whole 'nother story. If I wanted to port one of my apps from those days, I would definitely start fresh using Cocoa and Swift. It's just so much more advanced, faster to develop with, and less prone to errors and bugs. The resulting application will be 64-bit because that's the architecture of modern CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

After some investingation, it appears that OS X graphics is completely different from others. Screen is regarded as a target for vector graphics, not bitmap.

When the user changes the screen resolution, the screen resolution doesn't really cange (as it would in Linux or Windows) and remains native, but the scale at which the vector graphics is rendered changes. Consequently, it's perfectly possible to set screen "resolution" to be higher than the native one - you just see the things renderd smaller.

When you take a screenshot, the system simply renders everything to an off-screen bitmap (which can be any size), so you can get nice smooth screenshots at any size.

As everything is vectored, the applications that use bitmap graphics are at a huge disadvantage. It is very hard to get to native pixels without much overhead, and worse yet, an application that uses native pixels will behave strange because it won't scale when the user changes screen resolution. It also will have problems when screenshots are taken. Is it possible to make it work? I guess I won't find out until I fork over $2K for Macbook Pro and try it.

32-bit apps seems to be supported, and I don't think there's an intent to drop the support.

As to code distribution, my Thawte Authenticode certificate is supposed to work on OS X as well, so I probably don't need to become a member of Apple Developer program to distribute software, but again there's no definitive answer to that until I try.